# Commiting to non master branch and the contribution calendar

Tags: git, github

I have my own repository on github. And I noticed that some commits don't show in the contribution calendar when they aren't made to the master branch. I perceive this ridiculous and not making any sense. What if I commit to the develop branch and other ones and only sometimes merge the changes to master? The contribution calendar will be mostly white.

And I even didn't find any mention about this at github help.

Does this really work that way? Is there any logic in it?

Comment: Have you tried contact GitHub with this question?

Comment: @larsks, I believe here I'll get the answer more quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Github does not display contributions to any other branches other than the [default one](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch) (which doesn't have to be `master`).

So if you're contributing to a `develop` branch in any repo, you should see these on your profile if `develop` is set as the default branch in that repo.

See more details and all rules on the [GitHub Help page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile).

---

btw. the help page was just a click away from the profile page
[image]

Comment: 1) how do I make develop the default branch? 2) what will happen if in the future I'll change the default branch for the repo?

Comment: 1) I mean, the default branch for the particular repository (not for all ones)?

Comment: Re 1) I've added [link](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch) to the original answer Re 2) I don't know but I'd reckon it will stay there as it would take quite time to recalculate stats for all contributors + I don't see reason to do that (if I'd be Github). It was true contribution at that time.